# OAuthException (#368) The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I'm trying to post a feed on my wall or on the wall on some of my friends using Graph API. I gave all permissions that this application needs, allow them when i make the request from my page, I'm having a valid access token but even though this exception occurs and no feed is posted. My post request looks pretty good, the permissions are given. What do I need to do to show on facebook app that I'm not an abusive person. The last think I did was to dig in my application Auth Dialog to set all permission I need there, and to write why do I need these permissions. 
I would be very grateful if you tell me what is going on and point me into the right direction of what do I need to do to fix this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you're hitting some sort of spam block - don't think there's any way around that

Comment: Could it be possible the problem to come because of the domain from where I send this request

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I figured out that Facebook was refusing my shortlinks, which makes me a bit mad...but I get the point because its possible that shortlinks can be used to promote malicious content...so if you have shortlinks as part of your test, replace them w the full url...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this message is encountered for one of the two reasons :

1. Your post contains malicious links
2. You are trying to make a POST request over a non-https connection.

The second one is not confirmed but I have seen that behavior. While same code in my heroku hosted app worked fine, it gave this #368 error on my 000webhost hosted .tk domain which wasn't secured by SSL

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is still struggling with this, the problem occurs when you put URLs or "action links" that are not in your own app domain, if you really need to post to an extarnal page, you'll have to post to your app first, then redirect from there using a script or something. hope that helps.

also it's better in my opinion to use HTTPS links, as sometimes i've seen a behaviour where http links would be rejected, but that's intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

I started noticing that recently as well when running my unit tests. One of the tests I run is submitting a link that I know Facebook has blocked to verify that I handle the error correctly. I used to get this error:

**Warning: This Message Contains Blocked Content: Some content in this message has been reported as abusive by Facebook...**

But starting on July 4th, I started receiving this error instead:

**(#368) The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed'**

Both errors indicate that Facebook doesn't like what you're publishing.

Comment: the problem is that I want to make a single record on my own wall with hello world. I can't find anything abusive or deemed in this sentence. maybe I should encode or escape somehow the string I want to post.

Comment: I've seen publishing being rejected with this error on one Facebook page, but the exact same post on another FB page goes through successfully. I can't tell if it's a Facebook bug or something else. I'd suggest trying with a different account or different app ID to isolate the issue.

Comment: Sorry for dragging this up but did you manage to fix this? I've been getting this error using the post command in the sdk example documentation and can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Chris, this is not an error that you try to fix, just be able to handle it correctly. If a URL is blocked by Facebook, you can only publish it if you contact Facebook and manage to convince them to remove the block on that domain.

Comment: This is what I am getting
type: OAuthException, code: 368, error_subcode: 1404123, message: As a security precaution you can't take this action because your computer may be infected with a virus or a malicious browser extension.\n\nYou can learn more about malicious software here [HTTP 400]