# code to post posts on a page gives error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Following is my code:

```
    <?php
        try {
            $attachment = array(
                'message' => $_POST['message']
            );
            $result = $facebook->api('/$pageid/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
            var_dump($result);
        } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            var_dump($e->getType());
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    ?>
```

I get the following error: "OAuthException" string(78) "(#368) The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed". What's wrong here? I tried to post using facebook's graph API explorer, using the same access token and the post was successful. The error is displayed despite of whatever message is being posted.

Edit: I think this problem is being caused because of the reasons i've described in this post : [OAuthException (#368) The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372890/oauthexception-368-the-action-attempted-has-been-deemed-abusive-or-is-otherwi/15827225#15827225) but i'm not sure yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372890/oauthexception-368-the-action-attempted-has-been-deemed-abusive-or-is-otherwi#